# Order of execution of $http callbacks

Tags: angularjs, http, callback, factory

It seems that factory methods execution priority is the highest, so that callbacks has no data to deal with. What is the best way to make this work?

I got this kind of factory

```
app.factory('jsonService', function($http) {
    return {
        getDistricts: function(callback) {
            $http.get('data/districts.json').success(callback);
        },
        getLocations: function(path,callback) {
            $http.get('data/'+path+'.json').success(callback);
        }
    };
});
```

And controller

```
var app = angular.module('sandbox', []);
app.controller('sandboxCtrl',function ($scope,jsonService) {

 //This one works
    $scope.init1= function(){
        jsonService.getDistricts(function(data){
            $scope.districts = data;
            $scope.currentDistrict = $scope.districts[0].name;

             jsonService.getLocations($scope.currentDistrict,function(data){
            $scope.locations1 = data;

        })
        });

    };
    $scope.init1();

    //This one does not 
    $scope.init2= function(){
        jsonService.getDistricts(function(data){
            $scope.districts = data;
            $scope.currentDistrict = $scope.districts[0].name;
        })
        jsonService.getLocations($scope.currentDistrict,function(data){
            $scope.locations1 = data;
        });

    };
    $scope.init2();

});
```

Here is working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WjlDIejiCmrDZXFrzKU1?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular has an implementation of promises named $q ([documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)) that you should read up upon.

There is a race condition due to the async nature of http calls.  Please review the updated code linked to below that shows an example of your code running (successfully) using promises to handle your two calls in succession.

So upon success of your first call it will call your second service method all without using callbacks thanks to the power of promises.

```
jsonService.getDistricts()
  .success(function(data) {
    $scope.districts = data;
    $scope.currentDistrict = $scope.districts[0].name;
    jsonService.getLocations($scope.currentDistrict)
      .success(function(locationData) {
        $scope.locations = locationData;
      })
  });
```

[updated PLKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/9hceIfIBDw1WW1nzb0P1?p=preview)

Promise clarification:
The raw implementation of basic promises uses `then` to handle responses and promises returned from `$http` add additional methods (`success`, `error`) that will unpack your data from the response object that you would need to handle if your just use `then`.

Comment: +1 OP: I think that you should accept this answer, it's much better than mine. However, have a look at the examples that I've given in my answer, they could be a good complement for this one.

Comment: Also, notice that it's not a good idea to unwrap the promises in the service, because that adds unnecessary coupling to your factory.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. But could I still call .getLocations in separated function with this approach or do I have to bind it to .success() or .then() methods necessarily?

Comment: @vitto_primatti you can define the function that makes the call to `getLocations` on `$scope` or as a separate function and refer to it within the promise resolution.

Comment: @Josep Thanks your examples are solid and clearly show the differences between using `then` and `success` for `$http` promises.

Answer (score 1):

`init1()` is the correct way of doing this. `init2()` does work because `jsonService.getLocations()` is getting invoked before `jsonService.getDistritcs()` completes. The angular `$http` service is asynchronous. Since `jsonService.getLocations()` depends on data from `jsonServicd.getDistricts()` you must wait until `.getDistricts()` completes before calling `.getLocations()`. One way to do that is to call `.getLocations()` within the `.getDitricts()` callback, just as you did in `init1()`.

Comment: init1() is the correct way of doing this? I disagree, I think that the service should return the promise instead of unwrapping them.

Comment: There are multiple ways of doing this. When I said `init1()` was the correct way of doing it, I meant in comparison to `init2()`. It is his choice whether he wants to use callbacks or promises.

Comment: I'm not saying that you answer is wrong, because it isn't, actually  you made a good point by pointing out that the calls of the $http service are asynchronous, and that therefore if you want to consume the data provided by one of them you will have to wait until that data comes back... So, +1 for that. However I think that the root of the problem is that the OP doesn't understand how promises work in angular.